# Is there a way to make sublime text or any other editor use gcc or g++ that is on the windows linux subsystem on windows 10?

Tags: gcc, sublimetext3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Basically I want to find a way to use the gcc and g++ compilers that I have installed in the Linux Subsystem on my version of windows with any text editor.

I know on Linux you can build and run your C programs from sublime text. So has anyone found a way to interact with the WSL outside of bash?

Thanks and sorry for the confusing question.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass any command to `bash.exe` using the `-c` switch, e.g. `bash -c "ls"` launches bash and lists the CWD. See the [WSL Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/reference) for details.

I'm not on Windows, but you could try and translate this to a build-system for Sublime Text. Create a new build system (*Tools > Build System > New Build System…*) and copy & paste the following:

```
{
  "selector" : "source.c",
  "cmd" : ["bash", "-c", "gcc \"$file_name\" -o \"${file_base_name}\""],
  "shell": true, /* or false? */
  "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
}
```

Please let us know if it works and I'll edit the example accordingly!

**Update:** Regarding error 0x80070057, you might have to disable legacy console in your Command Prompt properties (see the [FAQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq#why-do-i-get-error-0x80040306-when-i-try-to-install) or this [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/7) for details!)

Comment: this  command works when i run it on Command Prompt `bash -c "cd /mnt/c/Users/Camilo/Desktop/ & gcc task5.c & ./a.out"`  but i  still get the same null error, even when I try a simple print hello program

Answer (score 1):

This would be the answer, however you need to be running at least build #14951 of Windows 10, which is available only through Insider beta program. The reason is bash on windows by default has only stdio implemented - no pipes support (as in: will return error 0x80070057 if you try to use it in Sublime Text). As said, support has already been added, but since WSL is very much a beta thing, you need to be running latest Windows 10 builds. As a bonus, if you update, you'll have Ubuntu 16.04 support instead of 14.04

Sources:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2
- https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13250514-allow-native-win32-applications-to-launch-wls-exec
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/19/interop-between-windows-and-bash/

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answers here, you can use this mod of sublimeGDB that I made. 
It's working with sublime text 3 and GDB. some bugs, but works.
You just need to clone it to the sublime plugging folder and remove the "_WSL".
https://github.com/Vinggui/SublimeGDB_WSL